# Algorithm to check sum of numbers from several ranges wanted

Tags: algorithm

i'd like to know if there is more optimal algorithm for the case below than simple iterating over the collection of items.

Suppose there are several items (2-10) with weight defined as range and increment, like
Item1 [0, 50] increment = 5
Item2 [40, 60] increment = 10.

The task is to check if there is at least one combination of weights which sum up to 100.
In the example above there are 50+50 and 40+60 combinations.

As the number of items is not big iterating over all items weights wouldn't take much time but maybe there is a better way.

Thanks

UPDATE: i look for algorithm which doesn't require the list of all possible weights or weights sum, i need algorithm which checks if there is at least one combination of weights equals 100 just knowing the range and increment

Comment: Simple iterating? what is this simple iterating? As I can think about this there is a brute force or DP not simple iterating.

Comment: by simple iterating i mean creation of the list of each item possible weights and then summation of these weights one by one. I suppose you mean the same by brute force

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be a version of the **[subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)**, which is NP-complete. Hence the answer is no, there probably isn't an efficient algorithm in the general case. Some **[heuristics](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.55.3431)** may help you achieve good results though.

Comment: Interestingly, I believe the conventional subset sum problem on any one of these sets {x,x+n,x+2n,...,y} is at most O(T) for a target sum T. (Maybe even less, but I couldn't do better.)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this right, we're given some total T (with T=100 in this case), and k pairs of ranges and intervals

([x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub>], n<sub>1</sub>), ([x<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>], n<sub>2</sub>), ..., ([x<sub>k</sub>,y<sub>k</sub>], n<sub>k</sub>)

and for each of them we've got to pick a value

a<sub>i</sub> ∈ {x<sub>i</sub>, x<sub>i</sub>+n<sub>i</sub>, x<sub>i</sub>+2n<sub>i</sub>, ..., y<sub>i</sub>}

so that

a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub> + ... + a<sub>k</sub> = T

So basically, the problem is to find values c<sub>i</sub> satisfying

x<sub>1</sub>+c<sub>1</sub>n<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>2</sub>+c<sub>2</sub>n<sub>2</sub> + ... + x<sub>k</sub>+c<sub>k</sub>n<sub>k</sub> = T

subject to the constraints

0 ≤ c<sub>i</sub> ≤ (y<sub>i</sub>-x<sub>i</sub>)/n<sub>i</sub> for all i.

I believe this is what they call a *linear integer constraint satisfaction problem*. The general class of approaches for these kinds of problems is called [integer linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Integer_unknowns). Such problems are usually NP-complete (though I don't know nearly enough to comment on this specific case), but I think there are still some relatively efficient heuristics.

In fact, this belongs to an even more specific subset of problems, as all the variables c<sub>i</sub> can only take a finite number of values (being integers, bounded above and below). Some Googling for CLP(FD) (constraint logic programming on finite domains) might give you an idea of how these  are approached in general (though again, this may be a special case with an easier solution that I'm unaware of).

Answer (score 0):

You can build up a set of all the possible weights you can produce. Weights above the total are discarded.

```
def weight_sum(items, total):
    possible = set([0])
    for weight_range, increment in items:
        new_possible = set(possible)
        for w in xrange(weight_range[0], weight_range[1] + 1, increment):
            new_possible.update(p + w for p in possible if p + w <= total)
        possible = new_possible
    return total in possible

items = [[[0, 50], 5], [[40, 60], 10]]
print weight_sum(items, 100)
-> True
print weight_sum(items, 111)
-> False
```

Answer (score 0):

Brute force in Python (I assume that each sum must contain weights from all items):

```
from itertools import product

goal = 100
items = dict(Item1=range(0, 51, 5), Item2=range(40, 61, 10))

print(any(sum(weights) == goal for weights in product(*items.values()))) # True
```

Where `product()` is a Cartesian product:

```
>>> list(product(range(1, 3+1), range(40, 60+1, 10)))
[(1, 40), (1, 50), (1, 60), (2, 40), (2, 50), (2, 60), (3, 40), (3, 50), (3, 60)]
```